# Сделать элемент с анимацией адаптивным

Tags: html, css

```css
.progress__bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/dTVvGm/js_skill.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateZ(-33deg);
  height: 32px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 85px;
  animation: example 5s linear 2s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 40px 26px;
}
span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 139px;
  left: 138px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: green;
}
@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(-33deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(148deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__bar">
  <img class="arrow" src="https://image.ibb.co/dp9pbm/Untitled_1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/QaxEPM

Comment: А можно узнать самый маленький размер? Какой примерно он должен быть?

Comment: самая минимальная ширина экрана 300px. 
А в данном блоке главное адаптивность, иначе смысла в анимации не будет

Answer (score 1):

Все значения в процентах, поэтому задавайте любую ширину для родителя:

```css
.cont {
  width: 140px;
}

.cont2 {
  width: 220px;
}

.progress__bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/dTVvGm/js_skill.png") no-repeat center bottom / cover;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateZ(-33deg);
  height: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 0 -2% -18%;
  animation: example 5s linear 2s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 80% 80%;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 139px;
  left: 138px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: green;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(-33deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(148deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="progress__bar">
    <img class="arrow" src="https://image.ibb.co/dp9pbm/Untitled_1.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont2">
  <div class="progress__bar">
    <img class="arrow" src="https://image.ibb.co/dp9pbm/Untitled_1.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот просто надо задать ширину `progress__bar` в пикселях. Это будет `254px` И нормально подойдет вам. А уже его расположение можете менять как угодно.

```css
.progress__bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/dTVvGm/js_skill.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 128px;
  width: 254px;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateZ(-33deg);
  height: 32px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 85px;
  animation: example 5s linear 2s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 40px 26px;
}
span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 139px;
  left: 138px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: green;
}
@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(-33deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(148deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__bar">
  <img class="arrow" src="https://image.ibb.co/dp9pbm/Untitled_1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с svg, может кому-нибудь пригодится.

```css
.main {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
}
```

```html
<svg class="main" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <path d="
             M56,60
             L27,31
             A100,100 0 0 0 0,100
             L40,100
             A60,60 0 0 1 56,60
             Z"
          fill="#ffc815"/>
    <path d="
             M140,56
             L169,27
             A100,100 0 0 0 31,27
             L60,56
             A60,60 0 0 1 140,56
             Z"
          fill="#a3cd3b"/>
    <path d="
             M160,100
             L200,100
             A100,100 0 0 0 173,31
             L144,60
             A60,60 0 0 1 160,100
             Z"
          fill="#0093d7"/>
    <path class="arrow"
          d="
             M60,100
             L100,90
             A10,10 0 0 1 100,110
             Z"
          fill="#3e3d40">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="rotate"
                        from="0 100 100"
                        to="180 100 100"
                        fill="freeze"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="1"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
```

Вот [здесь](https://codepen.io/dima74/pen/zpeQwP) можно попробовать изменять параметры (радиусы и другие).